# What is the name of the default D&D 4E world containing the Nentir Vale?

Tags: dnd-4e, campaign-settings, nentir-vale

The 4E Essentials rules compendium describes the Nentir Vale as a region of the Dungeons and Dragons world, but it does not mention the name of the world.  Does it have a name?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't have one. It's just "the Points of Light setting".

Read more at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_campaign_settings#Nentir_Vale).

Comment: it does actually have a nickname of PoLand.